# Split a data frame into two or more data frames in Scala using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have got a dataset of 2 million records. I want to split it into 2 equal half's . I don't have any column with serial number so that I can apply a where condition over it and split it into 2. That may not be the right approach also but all i want to do is split a dataframe into 2 half's

sample code that i am using:

```
var invoiceData = sc.textFile("/Scala/InvoiceLine.csv");
def removeheader (x : RDD[String]): RDD[String] = {
  x.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, lines) => {
    if (idx == 0) {
      lines.drop(1)
    }
    lines
  })
}
var invoiceWithoutHeader = removeheader(invoiceData);
var invoiceSchemaString = invoiceData.first().toUpperCase().split(",").map(_.trim());
var invoiceSchema = StructType(invoiceSchemaString.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
var invoiceRowRDD = invoiceWithoutHeader.map(y => {
  var parser = new CSVParser(',');
  parser.parseLine(y)
}).map { x => Row.fromSeq(x) } 
var invoiceDF = sqlContext.applySchema(invoiceRowRDD, invoiceSchema);
```

Now I want to split the invoiceDF into 2 parts, 1 million each
as I am a beginner, The code may not be efficient excuse me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If randomizing the data isn't a problem, you can just use `randomSplit()`:

```
val Array(half1, half2) = invoiceDF.randomSplit(Array(0.5, 0.5))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Randomizing is not a problem.

Comment: Is there a way to do splitting WITHOUT randomizing? I want to split basing on some condition, say column value >= 0.5

Comment: If you have some condition, then you can just use filter function